# Executing CURL shell command using system() doesn't block as expected

Tags: c++, linux, shell, curl

I'm trying to download a file from a server using:

```
system("curl -o filename.jpg --max-time 60 --connect-timeout 60 http://server/pic?source=1");
```

Now, I need to block here until the download completes, but I don't. 
I'm not able to figure out the reason for this.

Is this behaviour specific to CURL shell commands? 
How can I block until the file downloads?

PS: I wanted to avoid libcurl C++ calls as I'm only doing a single download (and upload possibly) and I'm not very bothered about the command output.

Comment: Are you checking the return value from system("curl..")? If it fails immediately...